# cd.. command does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I made a directory in my ubunto desktop and copied some file inside it.

I tried to go inside the directory by using the terminal.

the issue I have is when I want to back to the parent directory which is "Desktop" by using "cd.." command I got an error says `cd..: command not found`

I'm a newbie and want to know the reason.
would you explain it for me.
thank you

Comment: For future reference, this is not a programming question and is therefore off-topic here. Posts about how to use your computer or operating system belong on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) instead. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more information about the types of question that belong here. Staying on topic keeps noise and clutter down and helps SO stay a useful programming question and answer site. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need space, after command `cd`

```
cd ..
```

Comment: thanks. I started practicing unix commands by Putty and in the putty cd.. works.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the space in between `cd` and `..`:

```
cd ..
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space, should be `cd ..`